# General approach for object oriented rendering framework in DirectX 9?

Tags: c++, directx

I'm writing a graphics engine in C++ and DirectX 9, which I intend to use in a game in a later stage. Some time ago, I wrote a fully functional 2D engine and a basic 3D engine in OpenGL, but now I decided to start a new project in DirectX 9.

In my previous engines, I made a `std::vector` of type `Entity` which could contain subtypes like `Tank`, `Weapon`, `Particle`, etc. I would then, via polymorphism, do something like '`for each Entity in std::vector do Entity->Draw()`'. The draw function would do `glVertex3f(...)`.

Now my question is: how do you implement a similar object oriented framework in DirectX 9? I was thinking about keeping an array of vertices for each type (`Tank`, `Weapon`) which is loaded from a file, copying all vertices of all objects to the same vertex buffer en then calling `DrawPrimitive` for each subset of vertices. Is this the proper way to do this / the general way? Or should you create different vertex buffers for different objects in the scene for example? Some pseudocode would be nice to illustrate the correct implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what your aim is, if you want efficiency, you could load your meshes in a `std::unordered_map` with an associated handle, same for textures, then this would allow you to instance the vectors of the same object type.

If you want to keep it more simple, you could just create a container that stores all the entities and theer needed rendering info (similar to your 'old' engine), though will might want to use a culling data structure as well (like an [Octree](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Introduction_To_Octrees.shtml)):

```
class RenderInfo
{
    IDirect3DVertexBuffer9* pVertex;
    IDirect3DIndexBuffer9* pIndex;
    //...
};

class EntityController
{
    std::vector<std::pair<Entity,std::shared_ptr<RenderInfo>>> Entities;
    void Draw()
    {
        foreach e in Entities
            e.first.Draw(e.second);
    }
}
```

Here `std::shared_ptr<RenderInfo>` would be unique to a VB/IB pair, to avoid unneeded duplication

Comment: Let's say I would implement your simple approach to the problem (and then maybe instancing of the same objects in a later stage). What would you do in the Draw function of the Entity? Copy its vertices to the VB, call DrawPrimitives() and empty the VB for each Entity in the Entities vector?

Comment: You should keep one vb and one ib for each different mesh. Simply activate the correct ones before rendering. Don't change the contents of them. Graphics cards are optimized for static vb/ib. By changing the contents of a vb/ib you generate a lot of traffic between the GPU and the CPU.